Need to connect to WiFi through USB adapter on fresh install
I'm trying to connect my old server (Ubuntu Server ver 22.04) to WiFi. I recently moved house, and my internet access changed. At my old apartment I had easy access to an ethernet port. However, at my new place I don't this anymore, so I need to use a WiFi adapter (an old Netgear WNDA3100).
I can't see the adapter on in /sys/class/net and the solutions I've seen online are to clone various git repos and run modprobe, but I don't have internet access to clone.
I've also tried to set up my /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml in the mean time by adding
wifis:
   enp0s31f6:
     access-points:
       WIFI-SSID:
         password: pass
     dhcp4: true

But sudo netplan apply fails with subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['systemctl', 'start', 'netplan-wpa-wlan0.service']' returned non-zero exit status 1
I'm currently working off the assumption this fail is because of the network can't be reached.
Can I get my machine setup in the state it's in now? Or do I need to move the server into the utility closet?
Thanks!

You say the WiFi device is old. If it is so old maybe it is to old for the OS to support it or have support available for it. I Just looked it up, max OS it supports is Windows 8. Suggest get a newer device. https://www.netgear.com/home/wifi/adapters/wnda3100/

There isn't any hope for that WNDA3100 and your netplan is using enp0s31f6 and that is an ethernet device
